# Please help me in this question about Capacitance?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I know its old but still I have 3 doubts...

First: Suppose a charged capacitor is connected to an un charged capacitor as in image

[image]

Now I know there is a flow of charge from C1 to C2 due to difference in Voltage. But how the heat is lost. Is it because some work is done in moving the charge and some is converted to heat or is it because the energy is lost as heat due to flow of current and some resistance. What if the resistance is 0

Second: Is this a parallel combination or series, if it is parallel, how do we connect in series or vice versa.

Third: If I connect the circuit to a battery of voltage same as that of C1 like in the 2nd image, will the charge flow from C1 to C2?
[image]

Please answer, I m confused since 2 days
:(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you asked this recently

Comment: @VincentThacker I am not satisfied with that and I asked only first part.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with a totally non-descriptive title

Comment: Please [try to write more descriptive question titles](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583) and ask only a single question at a time.

Answer (score 3):

1. If the connections between the capacitors have low resistance then there is a rapidly changing current when the capacitors are connected. This creates a rapidly changing magnetic field and this is where the energy is lost. If the connections have high resistance then the current changes slowly, but this time energy is lost as heat in the resistive connections.
2. Since the left side of the capacitors is at one voltage and the right side is at a different voltage, the capacitors are in parallel. If you want to connect them in series then you would have to introduce a voltage source (such as a battery) between the capacitors on one side of the circuit.
3. If the voltage of the battery is the same as the voltage to which the first capacitor is charged, then no charge flows from one capacitor to the other. Instead the battery charges the second capacitor to the same voltage as the first.

Answer (score 0):

**A:** By energy comparison, we can see initial energy of the system is Q^2/2C and final is Q^2/4C. Hence, energy is lost because some work is done in moving the charge. It's not heat loss because no resistances are involved.

**B:** Series connection.

**C:** C1 will be Open ckt. so no such flow.

Comment: In the third question, why charge does not flow from positive plate of C1 to left plate pf C2

Comment: Bcoz the left plate is already at V potential ,it's directly connected to the battery.